# Using a list of values from train_test_split() as training data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a linear regression on some data. This is what the data looks like.

`X = df['vectors']` looks like this:

```
0      [-1.86135, 1.3202, 0.023501, -2.9511, 1.62135,...
1      [0.5487195, 0.27389452, 0.49712706, 0.6853927,...
2      [-1.3525691, -0.8444542, 2.8269022, -1.4456564...
3      [1.0730275, -0.14970247, -1.1424525, -1.953272...
4      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

When I run the linear regression model on it:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

How can I turn values in X into a scalar? I was thinking of getting the average of the vectors but not sure exactly how to go about it.

Comment: Do all the lists inside `X` have the same number of elements inside them?

Comment: @ArturoSbr yes they do, they're all padded.

Comment: `X` doesn't look like a list, it looks like a `pd.Series` of the stratified splits for cross-validation, where the index is the number of the fold, and the value is itself a list (of numeric values). Instead of assuming you know the type of `X`, better to check the value of `type(X)` and `type(X.loc[0])`.

Comment: Who said `X` is a list?

Comment: *"How can I turn values in X into a scalar?"* is the wrong question to ask. You actually do want the training to see each individual value in the list, for that CV fold. So this is simply a syntax question about how to pass a Series-of-lists-of-numerics to `lm.fit`.

Comment: it is actually a series (<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>). Sorry for the confusion on my part.

Comment: Don't worry. Did the answer I posted help? Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Yes, it did! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, `X` is a `pandas.Series` object.

Since all the lists inside each row of `X` are the same length, you can reshape `X` into an ndarray with the same number of rows as `X` and as many columns as there are elements in each list.

```py
# Import numpy
import numpy as np

# Reshape
X = np.array(X.explode()).reshape(len(X), -1)

# Do the same as before
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting that list in array using `numpy.array` and then make it two dimensional as `sklearn` works with arrays and it expects higher dimensional data.